# onPrimaryClipchanged() called multiple times in Android when text is copied from chrome browser

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I have implemented a listener for copy event and have overridden the `onPrimaryClipchanged()` method

This method get called thrice when some text is copied from the chrome browser. I know that this has something to do with the chrome. Is there anything that I can do to solve this problem?

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486370/onprimaryclipchanged-called-multiple-times-in-android). I had choice but to ask a similar question because I could not find any solution.

Comment: Well as commonsware explained there he had no idea, I think you can put  some boolean check around to handle your data only once.

Comment: How would I do a Boolean check?